# Pagination for dynamic store in extjs 3.2

Tags: extjs3

Can any one suggest on how can we do pagination when data is added dynamically in extjs store.

Results from the server is xml content and below code dynamically adds the data in the store. But this takes lot of time in rendering at UI.

So for improving the time, we need to do some pagination on it.

Below method takes lot of time:

```
success: function (response, request) {
    var responsexml = new ResponseXml(response.responseText);

    for (var i = 0; i < responsexml.items.length; i++) {
        var xmlItem = responsexml.items[i];
        var rec = somefuntion(xmlItem);
        Ext.getCmp('id').somegrid.store.add(rec);
    }
    Ext.getCmp('id').somegrid.store.commitChanges();
}
```

Please any one help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above link will help you:

http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/foss4g2010/workshop/web/Ext-3.2.1/examples/grid/paging.html

Please find the source file named "paging.js" for better understanding.